# Extarct worklog(work info) from BMC Remedy User for a set of Incident ID

Tags: remedy

Is there any way possible that I can extarct `worklog(work info)` from BMC Remedy User for a set of Incident ID using macro. I have extracted all the fields except "Worklog". Allthough I get the information that `This is a known issue and is on our Enhancements Requests list to be addressed.` Source -[Link](http://its.uncg.edu/Service_Management/Incident/Remedy/FAQ/)

So is there any way possible. Any type of information is highly acceptable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Worklog is a related table, the field on the Incident form does not store any information.  You'll need to query the HPD:Worklog form:
You can also post the question in the BMCDN communities, you will get more people looking at your questions.

https://communities.bmc.com/communities/community/bmcdn/bmc_it_service_support?view=overview

Answer (score 0):

There's no way I know of using a macro.  Macros have been deprecated.  So I'd recommend avoiding use of macros in any new code.  When I need to write code that extracts worklog information, I typically use an Active Link or Filter with a Set Fields action.